# Checking for specific integers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, compare, return-value

First post here so I'm hoping I don't screw up.

My task is to have a user enter an array of 10 integers and then input another integer separately and have the program either retrieve that number if it's in the array, or give an error if not.

I'm having trouble comparing the inputted integer with those in the array.

Here's part of my code, with the rest found below:

```
    try{

        System.out.print("Please enter 10 integers to store in an array and then press enter: ");

    for(int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
          numbers[index] = input.nextInt();

    if(numbers.length==10){ //method doesnt work properly if you input over 10 integers, only if you input less
        System.out.print("Thanks for entering 10 integers. Now input an integer to check: ");
        int compare = input.nextInt();

            if(numbers[index] == compare){     //this is where the error is I believe
                System.out.print(compare);     //here too
            }
```

http://pastebin.com/U5PdJgr6

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ok, but what is your question?

Comment: Has your question been answered? If so, please select the answer that was most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you can perform that easily using an `IntStream`

```
boolean contained = IntStream.of(inputtedNumbers)
                             .anyMatch(x -> x == numberToSearch);
```

Comment: Lambda expressions are the greatest things of all time! This is the best answer, but might be too advanced for the OP to fully understand.

Comment: `import java.util.IntStream;`

Comment: @4castle or CTRL + MAJ + O with Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Turn

```
if (numbers[index] == compare) {
    System.out.print(compare);
}
```

Into

```
boolean found;
for (int number : numbers) {
    found = number == compare;
    if (found) break;
}
if (found) System.out.print(compare);
else throw new Exception("Number Not Found");
```

**P.S.** You don't need to check to make sure `numbers.length` is still 10. The length of an array is always `final` and can't change.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have much experience with exception handling. Eclipse is giving me "NumberNotFoundException cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: I wrote `NumberNotFoundException` because you mentioned that it was part of your project. It isn't a built in exception, it's a class you would have to create that extends `Exception`. I've changed my answer now so that you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I've changed the for loop into a foreach loop now as well.

Comment: I've never seen a foreach loop before today, so I stuck with your first method. Is there a way to make this look a bit more user friendly?http://imgur.com/xUtMPp7

Comment: Exceptions are only useful if you handle them later in a catch block. This means that you should add `catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage()); }` after your try block.

Answer (score 0):

```
package integerarrayexceptions;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class IntegerArrayExceptions {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numbers[] = new int[10];

    try{

        System.out.print("Please enter 10 integers to store in an array and then press enter: ");

    for(int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) 
          numbers[index] = input.nextInt(); //The loop only applies to this statement.

    if(numbers.length==10){ 
        System.out.print("Thanks for entering 10 integers. Now input an integer to check: ");
        int compare = input.nextInt();

            for (int index2 = 0; index2 < numbers.length; index2++) {
                if(numbers[index2] == compare){
                System.out.print(compare);     
            }
            }

    }   
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException MismatchException)
    {
        System.out.print("One or more values entered is not an integer.");
    }   

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to use the variable "index" outside the "for" loop, where it does not exist...

Answer (score 0):

There's a loop missing after you entered the compare value:

```
for (index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {     
   if(numbers[index] == compare){
      System.out.print(compare);
   }
]
```